# looking for a particular question on the main site, cannot recall the title etc

Tags: discussion, specific-question

There was a question where the topic of illustrated math texts arose. I mentioned Galois' Dream, perhaps in a comment, I forget exactly.

Anyway, as I was shopping for affordable linear algebra texts I stumbled upon this gem:

[The Manga Guide to Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593274130)

This was published in 2012, and, is apparently one of an ongoing series of such texts. Now, as they currently stand it's not a stand-alone textbook, but it might be a fun supplemental for some courses. In any event, I'm mostly asking if anyone remembers the question where Galois' Dream came up and/or has a suggestion where I should add this on the main site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for this question: [Teaching advanced math using books with cartoons](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/4025/77)

In John Mangual's answer here: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/4029/77, he mentions the book *Galois' Dream*.  You commented on the answer: "I am so intrigued I just purchased a copy."